# assertAlmostEqual giving TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, despite isinstance check

Tags: pytest

I have some test code:

```
def assertSamplesEqual(self, a, b, msg=None):
  if isinstance(a.value, float) and isinstance(b.value, float):
    self.assertAlmostEqual(
        a.value, b.value, msg or
        'Samples %s and %s have different values' % (a, b))
  else:
    self.assertEqual(
        a.value, b.value, msg or
        'Samples %s and %s have different values' % (a, b))
```

I just swapped to assertAlmostEqual to better handle floats (I could get float or string values here, hence the isinstance conditional) and started getting the following error:

```
third_party/py/perfkitbenchmarker/test_util.py:52 in assertSamplesEqualUpToTimestamp
    self.assertAlmostEqual(
<embedded stdlib>/unittest/case.py:882 in assertAlmostEqual
    if round(diff, places) == 0:
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How can I be getting this string error from assertAlmostEqual, when I've just checked via isinstance that the values are floats?

I tried `print(type(a.value))` & got the expected `<class 'float'>` response.

Answer (score 0):

It was not a.value which was of type string, but rather the following parameter msg. Look at the [function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual) for assertAlmostEqual:
`assertAlmostEqual(first, second, places=7, msg=None, delta=None)` Note that the third parameter is places & the fourth parameter is msg. Since msg was my third parameter, it was being treated as places & resulted in the TypeError at the line `if round(diff, places) == 0:`.

My fix was pretty simple - add the parameter name msg=. So my new line is:

```
self.assertAlmostEqual(
          a.value, b.value, msg=msg or
          'Samples %s and %s have different values' % (a, b))
```

Tricky red herring - I doubted isinstance when I should have checked assertAlmostEqual!